# how do i make a loop to display the next 3 even number?

Tags: javascript

hello all i'm trying to make javascript to display an evens numbers by using a form with start number and number of evens to display. user will enter starting number and enter the number of even to display. 
say start at 7 number of evens is 3 should display 8 10 12.  just need some direction. thanks

my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>evens</title>
<div class="container">
           <h1>Enter Number</h1>
           <form name="number" class="form-inline">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="starting">Starting Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="starting" class="form-control">
           </div> <div class="form-group">
               <label for="step">numbers of evens</label>
               <input type="text" id="step" class="form-control">
           </div>
```

```
           <button type="button" onclick="evenDisplay()" class="btn" >submit</button>



<script>

function evenDisplay() {

    var starting = document.getElementById("starting").value;
    var step = document.getElementById("step").value;
    var evens = [];

    for (i = starting;  i <=12; i++) { /* this loop would show as much as evens number as long value of i<= set to  and doesn't care if the user enter the number of evens */ 
        i % 2 || evens.push(i);
    }
   console.log(evens)

}
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have a few tags that aren't closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several bugs in your code. I think i fixed it:

```
function evenDisplay() {

    var starting = parseInt(document.getElementById("starting").value);
    var step = parseInt(document.getElementById("step").value);
    var evens = [];

    for (i = starting+(starting%2), j=0;  j <step; i+=2, j++) {
        evens.push(i);
    }
    console.log(evens);
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = evenDisplay;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kirhchoff/pen/RgBmjX)

You need to add id="btn" to your button for this to work.

Btw definind event handlers in HTML is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = starting;  step==evens.length ;i++) {
    i % 2 || evens.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All looks well, but you're probably better with a while loop since you want to loop until `evens` contains `step` values.

```
var currentVal = starting;
while(evens.length < step){
   currentVal % 2 || evens.push(currentVal);
   currentVal++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using comas in your javascript where you should be using semi colons and you are missing numerous tags. Please see below for corrected code. I've included comments where you were missing things:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<title>evens</title>

<script>

function evenDisplay() {

var starting = document.getElementById("starting").value;  //SEMI-COLON HERE
var step = document.getElementById("step").value; //SEMI-COLON HERE
var evens = [];

for (i = starting;  i <=12; i++) { 
    i % 2 || evens.push(i);
}
  console.log(evens); //SEMI-COLON HERE
}
</script> <!--you had no closing script tag-->
</head> <!--you had no closing head tag-->
 <body> <!--you had no opening body tag-->
 <div class="container">
       <h1>Enter Number</h1>
       <form name="number" class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="starting">Starting Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="starting" class="form-control">
       </div> <div class="form-group">
           <label for="step">numbers of evens</label>
           <input type="text" id="step" class="form-control">
       </div>

       <button type="button" onclick="evenDisplay()" class="btn" >submit</button>
</form> <!--CLOSING FORM TAG HERE-->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks i should of have double check after i copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function evenDisplay() {

    var starting = parseInt(document.getElementById("starting").value);
    var step = parseInt(document.getElementById("step").value);
    if(!isNaN(starting)&&!isNaN(step)){
    var evens = [];
    var x=(step*2)+starting;
    for (i = starting+1;  i <=x; i++) { /* this loop would show as much as evens number as long value of i<= set to  and doesn't care if the user enter the number of evens */ 
        i % 2 || evens.push(i);
    }
   console.log(evens);
}

else{console.log("Nan");}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
           <h1>Enter Number</h1>
           <form name="number" class="form-inline">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="starting">Starting Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="starting" class="form-control">
           </div> <div class="form-group">
               <label for="step">numbers of evens</label>
               <input type="text" id="step" class="form-control">
           </div>

           <button type="button" onclick="javascript:evenDisplay();" class="btn" >submit</button>​
```

Here I use the equation =(step*2)+starting to loop with in the required range also I check if isNaN for the input values